# Reading from a file causes an error at the last line

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

The problem that I have is that, once I want to read the file, the program prints out everything, but it doesn't read the last element of the file.
So in the file lets say I have:

- admin:pass:1000:off
- test:testxx:1000:off
- ret:passx:1000:off

It prints out the first 2 lines and then it says "End of the buffer" (its just a printf that I put into the code in order to understand where is the problem).
After printing out "End of the buffer" it prints out the last line..
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */
#include <errno.h> /* perror */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* write, read, close*/
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> /*open */
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 500


struct utente{
    char username[MAX];
    char password[MAX];
    int gettoni;
    char stato[MAX];
    struct utente *next;
};

void menu(int);
struct utente* lettura_file(struct utente *);
struct utente* ins_coda(struct utente *t, char username[], char password[], char gettoni[], char stato[]);
void stampa_lista(struct utente*);
struct utente* elabora(struct utente *top, char buffer[]);
int check(struct utente *, char *);
void aggiornamento_file(struct utente *top);

int main(){
    while(1){
    char scelta[MAX], stringa[MAX];
    int i=0, res=0;
    struct utente *TOP=NULL;
    
    
    
    printf("1. STAMPA LISTA\nInserisci scelta --> ");
    scanf("%s", scelta);
    
    i=atoi(scelta);
    switch(i){
        case 1:
            TOP=lettura_file(TOP);
            stampa_lista(TOP);
            /*printf("Inserisci stringa da trovare: ");
            scanf("%s", stringa);
            res=check(TOP, stringa);
            if(res==1)
                aggiornamento_file(TOP);
            */
            break;
        }
    
    }
    return 0;
}



struct utente* lettura_file(struct utente *top){
    
    int fd, nread;
    char buffer[MAX];
    
    fd=open("utenti.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if(fd==-1){
        perror("ERRORE APERTURA FILE");
        return top;
    }
    
    while((nread=read(fd, buffer, MAX)>0)){
        top=elabora(top,buffer);
        }
        close(fd);
    
    return top;
}


struct utente* elabora(struct utente *top, char buffer[]){
    char username[MAX], password[MAX], gettoni[MAX], stato[MAX];
    int i=0;    
    int j=0; //indice username
    int k=0; //indice password
    int t=0; //indice gettoni
    int x=0; //indice stato
    int count=0;
    
    printf("Inzio buffer:\n%sfine buffer\n" ,buffer);
    
    while(buffer[i]!='\0'){
    
        //ELABORO NOME
        while(buffer[i]!=':'){
            username[j]=buffer[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        username[j]='\0';
        i++;
        
        //ELABORO COGNOME
        while(buffer[i]!=':'){
            password[k]=buffer[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        password[k]='\0';
        i++;
        
        //ELABORO GETTONI
        while(buffer[i]!=':'){
            gettoni[t]=buffer[i];
            t++;
            i++;
        }
        gettoni[t]='\0';
        i++;
        
        while(buffer[i]!='\n' && buffer[i]!='\0'){
            stato[x]=buffer[i];
            x++;
            i++;
        }
        stato[x]='\0';
        
        
        if(buffer[i]=='\n')
            i++;
        
        if(buffer[i]=='\0'){
            printf("\nEnd of the buffer %c\n", buffer[i]);
        printf("Fine%s %s %s %s\n\n", username, password, gettoni, stato);
        
        top=ins_coda(top, username, password, gettoni, stato);
            return top;
        }
        
        
        printf("Utente %d, %s %s %s %s\n\n", count, username, password, gettoni, stato);
        
        top=ins_coda(top, username, password, gettoni, stato);
        
        bzero(username, MAX);
        bzero(password, MAX);
        bzero(gettoni, MAX);
        bzero(stato, MAX);
        j=0;
        k=0;
        t=0;
        x=0;
        
    }
    
    return top;


}


struct utente* ins_coda(struct utente *t, char username[], char password[], char gettoni[], char stato[]){
    struct utente *p, *top;
    int n_gettoni;
    p=(struct utente*)malloc(sizeof(struct utente));
    
    strcpy(p->username, username);
    strcpy(p->password, password);
    n_gettoni=atoi(gettoni);
    p->gettoni=n_gettoni;
    strcpy(p->stato, stato);
    p->next=NULL;
    
    if(t==NULL)
        return p;
        
    top=t;
    while(t->next!=NULL)
        t=t->next;
        
    t->next=p;
    return top; 
}


void stampa_lista(struct utente *TOP){
    int i=1;
    while(TOP!=NULL){
        printf("Utente %d:\n Username: %s\nPassword: %s\nGEttoni: %d\nStato: %s\n", i, TOP->username, TOP->password, TOP->gettoni, TOP->stato);
        TOP=TOP->next;
        i++;
        }
    
    return;
}



int check(struct utente *top, char stringa[]){
    int len=strlen(stringa);
    while(top!=NULL){
        if(strncmp(top->username, stringa, len)==0){
        strcpy(top->stato, "on");
            printf("OK\n");
            return 1;
        }else{
            printf("KO\n");
            return 0;
        }
    top=top->next;  
    }
    return 0;
}




void aggiornamento_file(struct utente *top){
    char username[MAX], password[MAX], gettoni[MAX], stato[MAX]="";
    int fd;
    
    fd = open("utenti.txt", O_WRONLY |O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
            if(fd==-1){
                perror("ERROR apertura file utenti!");
                exit(1);
            }else{
                    while(top!=NULL){
                    strcpy(username, top->username);
                    strcpy(password, top->password);
                    sprintf(gettoni, "%d", top->gettoni);
                    strcpy(stato, top->stato);
                    
                    write(fd, username, strlen(username));
                        write(fd, ":", 1);
                        write(fd, password, strlen(password));
                        write(fd, ":", 1);
                        write(fd, gettoni, strlen(gettoni));
                        write(fd, ":", 1);
                        write(fd, stato, strlen(stato));
                        write(fd, "\n", 1);
                        
                        top=top->next;
                    }
        }       
    close(fd);
    return;

}
```

Comment: This string splitting may be confusing, so wouldn't it be more convenient for you to use strtok with ":" delimiter or sscanf?

Comment: There's kind of too much going on here to really give a coherent answer.  For one thing, you have `while(buffer[i]!='\0'){` in `elabora`.  Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't know where you would have an expectation to find a '\0'.  It may have nothing to do with the greater problem, but these little things are probably helping to obscure it.

Comment: Sure, but I want to understand why he is reaching the end of the buffer when there's one more line? It seems like it reads '\0' before the last line of the file

Comment: I suspect `'\0'` is just what *happens* to be underlying your  `char buffer[MAX];` under current conditions.

Comment: Why is this tagged C and C++? Pick one language.

Comment: You're using `open/read`. While this can be done, you're reinventing what `fopen/fgets` already does.

Comment: With `read`/`write` you must be ready to handle partial IO and buffering. `fread`/`fwrite` and other functions that work with `FILE *` already does that for you. Use them.  Don't use `"%s"` with `scanf`, and it is pointless when you want to parse the string as an integer anyhow.

Comment: This code certainly doesn't feel like the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue.  The burden is on the questioner to reduce the code.  In the process of doing so, you'll probably discover the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your file contains binary data and you actually put a `0x00` at the end of it, it shouldn't contain any zeros for the `buffer[i] != '\0'` check.

C strings are NULL terminated, but it's not usual to include this terminating zero when writing to text files. Text file editors don't do that either.

One problem is that you are not initializing the `buffer` variable.
Probably you are getting zeros by chance when the program allocates the 500 bytes for it.
One way you can initialize a buffer with zeros is by setting it's first element to zero at the declaration:

```
char buffer[MAX] = {0,};
```

Now, if I understood correctly your doubt, I don't see that the end of the file is happening before the program reads the last entry. What is happening there is that the program is printing the message with the last line after it prints the message of the end of the file. But the program did read the last line before the end of the file and stored it in the variables used by `printf`.

Confusion typically arises in codes with big functions. `elabora` function is big, complicated and hard to debug. You can make it simpler if you break it in smaller functions. I believe it gets much better if it reads lines instead of the whole file. I rewrote it quickly as an example:

```
void get_field(char **src, char dst[MAX])
{
    int j = 0;

    while (*(*src) && *(*src) != ':' && *(*src) != '\n') {

        dst[j++] = *(*src);
        (*src)++;
    }
}

struct utente* elabora(struct utente *top, char *line, ssize_t line_len, int *count)
{
    char username[MAX] = {0,};
    char password[MAX] = {0,};
    char gettoni[MAX]  = {0,};
    char stato[MAX]    = {0,};

    get_field(&line, username);
    get_field(&line, password);
    get_field(&line, gettoni);
    get_field(&line, stato);

    printf("Utente %d, %s %s %s %s\n\n", ++(*count), username, password, gettoni, stato);

    top = ins_coda(top, username, password, gettoni, stato);

    return top;
}
```

It can now be called from a function that reads the file by lines using `geline` function:

```
struct utente* lettura_file(struct utente *top)
{
    FILE  *file        = NULL;
    char  *buffer      = NULL;
    size_t buffer_size = 0;
    int count          = 0;
    ssize_t n_read     = 0;

    if ((file = fopen("utenti.txt", "r")) == NULL) {

        perror("ERRORE APERTURA FILE");
        return top;
    }

    while ((n_read = getline(&buffer, &buffer_size, file)) > 0) {

        top = elabora(top, buffer, n_read, &count);
    }

    if (buffer != NULL)
        free(buffer);

    if (file != NULL)
        fclose(file);

    return top;
}
```

These functions are still not safe, but I believe they have better readability and tend to be easier do debug. `strtok` would be better than parsing tokens this way. Using other functions for opening and reading the file, as suggested by the questions' comments, would also improve the code.